# Transitivity of normalness - a finite extension and a free extension?

Tags: group-theory

I know that in general being a normal subgroup is not a transitive property, however I am wondering if it holds in a particular special case that I am interested in.  I have 3 nested groups $G_1 \trianglelefteq G_2 \trianglelefteq G_3$ and in my special case I have two special properties:

(1) $[G_3 : G_2] < \infty$

(2) $G_2/G_1$ is a noncylic finitely generated free group.

My question: Does this imply that $G_1 \trianglelefteq G_3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $G_2$ be free of rank $4$, generated by $x,y,z,w$. Let $G_1$ be the normal closure of $\langle x,y\rangle$ in $G_2$. Then $G_2/G_1\cong \langle z,w\rangle$ is free of rank $2$.

Now let $C_2$ act on $G_2$ by letting the nontrivial element exchange $x$ and $z$, $y$ and $w$, and let $G_3=G_2\rtimes C_2$. By construction, $G_2\triangleleft G_3$, $[G_3:G_2]=2\lt\infty$. But $G_1$ is not normal in $G_3$, because the nontrivial element of $C_2$ conjugates $G_1$ into the normal closure of $\langle z,w\rangle$, which is different from $G_1$.